# How to find values from one excel column and display a diff value in Col B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

```
   A                                        B (This is what I want)

Apple iPhone                                       Apple
Verizon Galaxy S6 (SM-G920F)                      Samsung
T-Mobile Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935F)                Samsung
Apple iPod Touch                                   Apple
```

i.e. Display Samsung in column B if column A contains the word "Galaxy" and  "Apple" if Column A contains the word "Apple".

I want to use an excel formula and not VBA. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table of the keyword to search and the expected outcome:

[image]

Then use this formula:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$2:$D$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$3,A2))),1))
```

[image]

If you do not want the extra table but want to hardcode the array you would do it thus:

```
=INDEX({"Apple","Samsung"},AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Apple";"Galaxy"},A2))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and talented as usual :). Yet I am eager to know why you have a tendency to use `Large 1` instead of max and Small 1 instead of min. Is that some kind of habit or is there a technical reason?

Comment: Inside the Aggregate With the small and large we can do Array type formulas that create arrays, but we can't with the MAX or MIN in the aggregate.  We could use MAX(IF()) or MIN(IF()) in its place but then we need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter and sometimes we forget when we edit and that is a hassle. @A.S.H

Comment: @Donny7 please mark the method you used as the correct method.  One does this by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Done. But is there a way to mark multiple answers as correct ones ?

Comment: @Donny7 no unfortunately, you mark the one you used as the correct answer and let the community upvote the others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula that you can use in column B:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("Apple",A1) > 0,FALSE), "Apple", IF(IFERROR(FIND("Galaxy",A1)>0,FALSE),"Samsung",""))
```

Here is the sample data with result:

[image]

This formula will leave the value blank if it won't find "Apple" or "Galaxy" in corresponding cell in column A.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Apple",A1)>0,"Apple"),"Samsung")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple";A1));A1;"")
```